# Is a short token lifetime for email confirmation necessary?

Tags: python, flask

I am using following code for email confirmation (if a user registers on my page).

In the tutorial it was recommended to set the token lifetime to 3600 seconds. But why is a short token lifetime used?

Sometimes the service needs a few minutes to send the email. Often the users do not wait and leave. When they check emails on the next day, they will see the confirmation email with the link, but it would not be valid anymore. Wouldn't a longer lifetime be better here? For example a few days or as I plan 24 hours:

```
def generate_confirmation_token(email):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return serializer.dumps(email, salt=app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'])


def confirm_token(token, expiration=86400): #old expiration was 3600 seconds = 1 hour
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        email = serializer.loads(
            token,
            salt=app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'],
            max_age=expiration
        )
    except:
        return False
    return email
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40512/how-long-should-an-e-mail-address-confirmation-link-last-and-why-must-it-expire

Comment: @moritzg, thanks. So in my case increasing it to 24 hours is absolutely no problem.